# Return all items or a single item from DynamoDB from AWS API Gateway endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS proxy with AWS API Gateway to interact with a DynamoDB table. I have an API resource, under which I have a GET method with the below configuration:

[image: API method description]

The API uses the `Scan` action as seen above to fetch all the items from the DynamoDB table. I also have the following request integration mapping template;

```
{
    "TableName": tableName
}
```

Its really simple. But my problem is that I would like to add another GET method to get each item by their `id`, which will be supplied in the URL as a `param`. However, since I have already setup one GET method, I am not able to setup another to fetch only a single item. I am aware I can use mapping templates and `Scan` as given [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) to conditionally fetch items if a param is given, but that would mean scanning the entire table, which is a waste each time I want to fetch a single item.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Usually you would create a new resource for it, e.g. `/contact`.

Comment: It would make sense for GET '/contacts' to fetch a list of contacts, while GET '/contacts/:id' would fetch a contact by it's ID.  You need to define another route instead of embedding the routing logic in your mapping template.